# How to install software packages on a shared Red Hat Linux host account without root access or rpm?

Tags: linux, installation, redhat, packaging

I have a shared RHEL 4 host account where I do not have root privileges. I would like to install Git and Bash Complete in a way that they can be upgraded easily.

To date, I've just been installing from source providing `$HOME` as a prefix to autoconf. Obviously this isn't ideal as I need to hunt down the files associated with the version I'm upgrading away from and delete them. I've tried using rpm but I just get `-bash: rpm: command not found` back so it's not available. I also looked into checkinstall but it looks like that requires rpm, dpkg, or Slackware's package manager to be available.

Is there anything out there that can be used like a package manager without requiring root access or an existing package manager?

Comment: Why not change to an account that's appropriate for your needs/wants?

Answer (score 1):

You need administrative rights to make system modifications. This design is part of what makes Linux a secure operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best to ask your host to install these packages for you - no doubt they do not allow their clients to manage packages so that they can maintain integrity and consistency across their server deployment.

Imagine if someone thought it would be a good idea to install an X server, wireshark, apache load tester... one client can have a massive impact on the performance of the entire server!

Answer (score 0):

[stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) can help you to manage the files, but you still have to care about dependencies and such.